# HTML & XHTML Elements That Are Centered Automatically

Tags: html, xhtml

can you list all the elements that are centered automatically without using style sheets like the <    th    > element.

Answer (score 2):

The `th`, `caption`, and `center` tags.

Comment: isn't center removed from xhtml? just being technical :D

Comment: @Crazy - No. XHTML 1.0 contains everything that HTML 4.01 contains.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html lists the default styling applied to each element

Comment: It contains typical styling. Not all browsers conform to that recommended stylesheet.

Comment: @David very true, and so long as not all browsers conform to it, an actual list of elements that are centered automatically is difficult with out making special notice of which browser supports which.  If the OP isn't going to use stylesheets to account for this I figured the typical list was most applicable

Answer (score 1):

`<th>` is not guaranteed to center the text. It just happens to be rendered like that in most browsers.

You can only rely on presentational elements and attributes, like `<center>` and `<p align=center>` for this.

Comment: Even then, the user might have overridden them with a local stylesheet.